# Copy paste .bat files

Tags: batch-file

Is there any way to copy the text thats typed in the .bat file while active, to another .bat file or a .txt file? 
So for example if you got asked to type a password (in the batchfile), the batchfile would copy it, and paste it to another file -

Comment: See [Can copy & paste be emulated in windows CMD?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43720258/463115)

Comment: It depends on how the password is asked. If you control the procedure yourself, then yes. If not, then no.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how the password is asked whether or not you have control over what was typed or not.

Batch scripting is very basic. Whatever is possible in commandline itself is possible in batch scripting, because batch scripting is nothing more than entering commands one by one with a very limited set of additional instructions.

If you have control over the entire process, then you can do the following:

```
    @echo off

::  -- Ask for password
    set /p Password=Please type in the password

::  -- Append the typed password to a logfile
    echo %date% %time% - The user typed %Password% >> log.txt

::  -- Parse password to program as parameter
    Program.exe -p %Password%
```

Answer (score 0):

An approach to performing this type of logging is to use a subroutine or macro to handle all the input / output rather than set /p every time input is needed.

As an example:

```
@echo off

REM MacroDefinition

setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
set LF=^


::Above 2 blank lines are required - do not remove
set ^"\n=^^^%LF%%LF%^%LF%%LF%^^"

Set @input=For /L %%n in (1 1 2) do if %%n==2 (%\n%
    For /F "tokens=1,2 delims=, " %%G in ("!argv!") do (%\n%
    Set /P "tmpV=%%~G" %\n%
    Set %%H=!tmpV!%\n%
    ECHO(!tmpV!^>^>log.txt %\n%
    ) %\n%
) ELSE setlocal enableDelayedExpansion ^& set argv=, 

REM Declare the prompt as argv 1 and the variable to be set as argv 2:

%@input% Name: Name

ECHO(!name!
pause
```

A note regarding this form of macro:

Excessive use without using endlocal will result in maximum recursion level being exceeded.